# How do you extend a task for Gradle when using Kotlin to implement a plugin?

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I feel like this answer for this is simple, however I can't find it.

I'm attempting to create a Gradle extension with Kotlin. The first task I'm doing is effectively calling the `project.copy` task so I can move the source files to the build directory and perform token replacement(I know, I haven't implemented that yet).

This compiles, and the plugin is recognized by Gradle. There are (at least) 2 problems. The compiler complains that `from` and `into` or not used. My first clue I'm doing something incorrectly. The second is that when I run the task Gradle tells gives me this error:

```sh
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gsqlCopySources'.
> Cannot convert path to File. path='null'
```

Code:

```
import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
import com.optum.giraffle.GsqlExtension
import org.gradle.api.tasks.*
import java.io.File

open class CopySources: DefaultTask() {

    private val extension = project.extensions.run {
        findByName("gsql") as GsqlExtension
    }
    @OutputDirectory
    val outputDirectory: File = project.file("${project.buildDir}/${extension.scriptPath}")

    @InputDirectory
    val inputDirectory: File = project.file("${project.rootDir}/${extension.scriptPath}")

    init {
        group = "build"
        description = "Copy gsql scripts to build directory performing token replacement"

    }

    @TaskAction
    fun copyFiles() {
        inputDirectory.apply {
            parentFile.mkdirs()
        }
        project.copy{
            val from = inputDirectory
            val into = outputDirectory
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the solution, it looks like the `from` and `into` are functions.

```
@TaskAction
fun copyFiles() {
    inputDirectory.apply {
        parentFile.mkdirs()
    }
    project.copy{ copySpec ->
        copySpec.from(inputDirectory)
        copySpec.into(outputDirectory)
    }
}
```

Comment: That is right. Translating from gradle to kotlin may cause this confusion. Actually inside copy you have access of `copySpec` as `this`, so you don't need actually specify a parameter

Comment: @EricMartori, Yes I experimented with using `this`, and it does work. The IDE I'm using suggested using an explicitly named parameter, so I did.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring new values for `from` and `into` instead of assigning the existing ones.

Your code should be:

```
    @TaskAction
fun copyFiles() {
    inputDirectory.apply {
        parentFile.mkdirs()
    }
    project.copy{
        from(inputDirectory)
        into(outputDirectory)
    }
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't work. I get unresolved references.